# Making Word Cloud from Twitter Search Data?

Tags: social-media, word-cloud

Is there a way to make a Mathematica word cloud of Twitter search data?

Example: Suppose you search twitter for "#Mathematica". This will bring up a bunch of tweets with other words than just "#Mathematica". It would be nice to make a word cloud of all these words to see what related concepts people are tweeting about alongside "#Mathematica". Is this possible?

Comment: Unfortunately, last I checked the `ServiceConnect["Twitter"]` functionality had not been updated to handle 280 character tweets, which made it difficult to use...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, sure.

```
twitter = ServiceConnect["Twitter", "New"];
result = twitter["TweetSearch", "Query" -> "#Mathematica", 
   MaxItems -> 50];
WordCloud@Flatten[Normal[StringSplit[#["Text"]] & /@ result]]
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work with Mathematica Online (https://mathematica.wolframcloud.com); should it?

Comment: Sorry, George, I don't have access to the online version. Try to run the code line-by-line. Where does a problem occur? I guess it is at the first line because you cannot login to the Twitter (API works only after this).

Comment: Correct. `ServiceConnect["Twitter", "New"]` returns `ServiceObject["TwitterNotConnected"]`.

Comment: Then establishing a connection to Twitter in Mathematica Online is a separate problem, which I cannot help you with. Good luck!

Comment: See for a new question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/170552/connecting-to-twitter-via-online-mathematica