# Connecting to Twitter via Online Mathematica?

Tags: mathematica-online, social-media

I am running Mathematica Online in chrome (on Linux), and get the following:

> [image]

Is this the expected behavior? If not, how do I get around this issue?

Comment: Do you get a authentication dialog page in your browser? Twitter connection still works for me in 11.3, but `ServiceConnect["Facebook", "New"]` gives an error message in chrome; Facebook seem to have changed something in their API so the authentication no longer works...

Comment: You should have been redirected (opened in a new tab or page in your browser) to Twitter authentification page to enter your ID and PWD for allowing Wolfram Language to use your Twitter account...